Cupy creating array using other variables
I am trying to make a numpy/cupy interchange script, similar to this backend implementation. Such that by using something like from Util.Backend import backend as bd, I can create bd.array() that can switch between numpy and cupy. But I had a lot of trouble doing so, especially about creating array.
After some experiments, it seems that an assignment in the form of:
import cupy as cp 
A = cp.array([1, 2, 3])
B = cp.array([A[0], A[1], 3])

Will result in error:
TypeError: Implicit conversion to a NumPy array is not allowed. Please use `.get()` to construct a NumPy array explicitly.

However, if the same array creation is written as:
B = cp.array([A[0], A[1], A[2]])

Then it becomes totally fine (which is also weird, since I did not import numpy at all in the example above, it's almost like [] is being created as a numpy array first).
Similarly,
s = 2
c = 3
one = 1.0
B = cp.array([s, c, one]) 

Is fine. But if some of the entries are not created in the same way, such as:
s = cp.sin(2)
c = cp.cos(1)
one = 1.0
B = cp.array([s, c, one]) 

Then the TypeError would come in again. Note that if numpy is used instead of cupy, none of the above array creation would have raised an error.
This post seem to indicate that cupy does not support a mix type data. But by the suggested method I would have to write CParray.get() to make the conversion, it is a cupy method and not a numpy one, thus will create new errors if that backend module is running numpy.
Would it be possible to find a way to write array creations so that cp and np are interchangeable?

A[0] is stored on the GPU device. Mixing CPU data with GPU ones is clearly a bad idea and is likely to be a bug (most people don't want this since it is inefficient) so this is certainly why it is forbidden. If all variable are on the device, the operation could be on the GPU in an implicit kernel (not very efficiently though since the indices are on the host and expensive operation are also done per item) though I agree this is a bit weird to accept that here. I guess it make more sense for list of large 1D arrays stored on the GPU device for example.

You should really avoid creating arrays that way since it is not efficient with cupy (moving data from/to the host/device through the PCIe/NvLink interconnect is inherently slow, especially when it is scalar). You can fill the array on the host and send it entirely on the device, or build it directly on the device (fastest solution but clearly cumbersome for small arrays).

If you do not care about performance of this, then you can write a function calling arr.get() based on the type of arr (e.g. it can even take the list -- to convert to an array -- in parameter).

@JérômeRichard these are super helpful insight, thank you! I totally forgot that a numpy array or a scalar created in python would be on CPU device. Using cupy to create scalars turned out to eliminate a lot of the problems

Problem is CuPy and NumPy handle implicit conversions differently. CuPy does not allow implicit conversion between NumPy arrays, Python scalars, or CuPy arrays when creating arrays, while NumPy is more permissive.
In solution you must do 1- Explicit type casting 2- Create a wrapper function that ensures all elements are compatible with the backend (numpy or cupy). This function can preprocess inputs to avoid issues.
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

class Backend:
    def __init__(self, use_cupy=False):
        self.backend = cp if use_cupy else np

    def array(self, data):
        # Convert all elements to the backend-compatible type
        backend = self.backend
        if backend == cp:
            # Ensure compatibility with CuPy
            data = [self._to_cupy_element(x) for x in data]
        return backend.array(data)

    def sin(self, x):
        return self.backend.sin(x)

    def cos(self, x):
        return self.backend.cos(x)

    def _to_cupy_element(self, x):
        # Ensure elements are CuPy-compatible
        if isinstance(x, (int, float, bool)):  # Python scalars
            return x
        elif isinstance(x, np.ndarray):  # NumPy array
            return cp.asarray(x)
        elif isinstance(x, cp.ndarray):  # CuPy array
            return x
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Unsupported type for CuPy: {type(x)}")

# Example Usage:
use_cupy = True  # Set to False to use NumPy
backend = Backend(use_cupy=use_cupy)

# Example 1: Create an array
s = backend.sin(2)
c = backend.cos(1)
one = 1.0
B = backend.array([s, c, one])  # Works seamlessly for both NumPy and CuPy
print(B)

Good luck!
